# Handle API to not receive value less than 0 (negative values)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I need to treat the API result so that I don't receive values less than 0, I've been trying this way and so far I haven't been able to:

```
private handleChart(data: Object): void {
    const series = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      series.push({
        name: key,
        data: value,
        type: "line",
      });
    }
    
    if (series[0].data.length < 0) {
      delete series[0].data;
    }
    console.log(data );  

    this.plotChart(series);
  }
```

Original code:

```
private handleChart(data: Object): void {
    const series = [];

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
      series.push({
        name: key,
        data: value,
        type: "line",
      });
    }

    this.plotChart(series);
  }
```

Comment: Why not do the check before you push to the series?

Comment: You can check before pushing to array. Why are you delete only data field?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data object is:

```
const obj = {'jan':100,'feb':200, 'mar':-100,'apr':250};
```

You can filter and map your Object.entries result like:

```
Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(arr=> +arr[1] >= 0)
  .map(arr=>{return{name:arr[0],data:+arr[1],type:'line'}});
```

The result would be:

```
[
 {"name": "jan","data": 100,"type": "line"},
 {"name": "feb","data": 200,"type": "line"},
 {"name": "apr","data": 250,"type": "line"}
]
```

Or if you want to floor the negative values:

```
 Object.entries(obj)
   .map(arr=>{return{name:arr[0],data:+arr[1] >= 0 ? +arr[1] : 0,type:'line'}});
```

Result:

```
[
 {"name": "jan","data": 100,"type": "line"},
 {"name": "feb","data": 200,"type": "line"},
 {"name": "mar","data": 0,"type": "line"},
 {"name": "apr","data": 250,"type": "line"}
]
```